# Лимит при записи в базу данных mysql

Tags: mysql

При попытке создания из csv файла базу данных размером 10000 строчек при помощи PHP получается писать по 850 840 строчек в потом останавливаться . Если перезапустить компьютер на котором стоить сервер то получаться 922 строки.
Есть идеи где лимит стоит ?

Comment: Если не сложно приведите кусок кода, которым вставляете данные? Используете многострочный INSERT или вставляете по одной записи в цикле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите с какой ошибкой останавливается скрипт
скорее всего ограничение по времени выполнения скрипта

Comment: set_time_limit(0); //unlimited time

Answer (score 0):

Следует снять ограничение скрипта по времени выполнения

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); 
?>
```